# Istio, no listener registered when ports are the same

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with 2 EC2 nodes. I want to use Istio with ALB not the classic ELB, so I modified the gateway from the Istio helm chart to use NodePort like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
    release: istio
    istio.io/rev: default
    install.operator.istio.io/owning-resource: unknown
    operator.istio.io/component: "IngressGateways"
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
  ports:
    -
      name: status-port
      port: 15021
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 32767
    -
      name: http2
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31231
    -
      name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31312
```

Also, I added the Ingress for the gateway:

```
    ---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: aws-load-balancer
spec:
  controller: ingress.k8s.aws/alb
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: ingress
  labels:
    app: ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: "32767"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz/ready
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-foo,subnet-bar
spec:
  ingressClassName: aws-load-balancer
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: istio-ingressgateway
            port:
              number: 80
```

The ALB and the TargetGroup are created as expected, the nodes are healthy according to the TargetGroup health check.

The sample bookinfo [stack](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/platform/kube/bookinfo.yaml) and [gateway](https://github.com/istio/istio/blob/master/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml) are installed to a labeled namesapce

```
% kubectl get ns bookinfo --show-labels                          
NAME       STATUS   AGE   LABELS
bookinfo   Active   18h   istio-injection=enabled
```

Istioctl shows the proxy status

```
% istioctl proxy-status
NAME                                                   CDS        LDS        EDS        RDS          ISTIOD                      VERSION
details-v1-79f774bdb9-2scfv.bookinfo                   SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
istio-ingressgateway-8579cc48f8-2d5sd.istio-system     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     NOT SENT     istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
productpage-v1-6b746f74dc-l795c.bookinfo               SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
ratings-v1-b6994bb9-l2vcp.bookinfo                     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
reviews-v1-545db77b95-shzkj.bookinfo                   SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
reviews-v2-7bf8c9648f-6k6mk.bookinfo                   SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
reviews-v3-84779c7bbc-6mw5f.bookinfo                   SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED     SYNCED       istiod-75c795985d-pwx9j     1.10.0
```

But when I try to reach it it gives back 502.

```
% curl http://internal-k8s-istiosys-ingress-foo-bar.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/productpage
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Istio version: 1.10
Kubernetes version: 1.19
EKS version: eks.5

Edit:

It turned out there are no listeners attached:

```
% istioctl proxy-config listeners -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-8579cc48f8-2d5sd.istio-system
ADDRESS PORT  MATCH DESTINATION
0.0.0.0 15021 ALL   Inline Route: /healthz/ready*
0.0.0.0 15090 ALL   Inline Route: /stats/prometheus*
```

However, if I change a port for the Gateway from 80 to 9000, the listeners created but it is need to match with the ingress-gateway port

```
% istioctl proxy-config listeners -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-8579cc48f8-qzn59
ADDRESS PORT  MATCH DESTINATION
0.0.0.0 9000  ALL   Route: http.9000
0.0.0.0 15021 ALL   Inline Route: /healthz/ready*
0.0.0.0 15090 ALL   Inline Route: /stats/prometheus*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody faces the same issue, it turned out that the default istio ingress gateway cannot bind to 80 since it is an unprivileged pod, updated the deployment specification, and now up and running.